# How can I use Realm with Swift 4?

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, xcode9-beta, swift4

I'm trying to run my current project in the new Xcode 9 beta, but when I do so it says `Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0`. How can I solve this problem? I'm not using cocoapods.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Update**: As of v2.10.1, released 2017-09-14, Realm's prebuilt binaries include frameworks built with Xcode 9 for Swift 3.2 and 4.0. It's no longer necessary to build them yourself.

The information below remains relevant to anyone looking to use Realm with prerelease versions of Xcode in the future.

---

If you're currently integrating Realm's prebuilt binaries, you'll need to switch to building Realm from source in order to support Swift 3.2 and 4.0, as Realm does not publish prebuilt binaries for prerelease versions of Xcode. You can build Realm from source in one of three ways:

1. Using CocoaPods.

   CocoaPods always builds dependencies from source.
2. Using Carthage.

   By default Carthage will attempt to download prebuilt binaries, but will fall back to building from source if the prebuilt binaries are for a different Swift version than the version of Xcode in use.
3. Build Realm manually from source, and then integrate the built frameworks as you would the prebuilt binaries that Realm provides.

   You can do this by checking out a release tag from Git:

   ```bash
   git clone --recursive https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa.git
   cd realm-cocoa
   git checkout v2.10.0
   ```

   Then run whichever of the following commands corresponds to the platform you care about to build the Realm Swift framework for that platform:

   ```bash
   REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=4.0 sh build.sh ios-swift
   REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=4.0 sh build.sh osx-swift
   REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=4.0 sh build.sh watchos-swift
   REALM_SWIFT_VERSION=4.0 sh build.sh tvos-swift
   ```

   The built frameworks will be placed in the `build` directory within the Realm source, where you can then integrate them as you did the prebuilt binaries that Realm provides.

   These built frameworks should also work with apps using Swift 3.2 due to it using the same compiler as Swift 4.0.

Comment: Could you explain the third option a bit more please? But thank you very much for replying

Comment: Is there something in particular that you'd like me to clarify?

Comment: You can run them in Terminal in a directory of your choosing.

Comment: Okay so I ran those commands in the Terminal and after that was done, I ran the command for iOS but when I try to run the project it still displays the same error

Comment: Did you then integrate the newly-built framework into your app? If not, your app will still be using the prebuilt framework, rather than the one you just built with Swift 4.0.

Comment: After building for iOS, the frameworks will be inside the build/ios/swift-4.0 directory within the realm-cocoa source directory. Are you saying you don't see the frameworks there?

Comment: there is no "build" folder in the realm-cocoa-master folder. Where's that folder supposed to be?

Comment: The directory is created when you run `sh build.sh ios-swift` or any of the other build commands I listed. If you're not seeing the directory, I'd suggest sharing the output you see from the `build.sh` invocation.

Comment: I couldn't build the framework as it was missing some of the source files. There's one more step to do after checking out realm sources. From Realm docs: If cloning from git, submodules are required: git submodule update --init --recursive

Comment: Good catch, @pteofil. I added the missing `--recursive` flag to the `git clone` invocation in the answer.

Comment: with Xcode 9 beta 4 and 2.9.0 I'm getting:
** BUILD SUCCEEDED **
...
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
  { name:iPhone 6 }

 Unsupported device specifier option.
 The device “My Mac” does not support the following options: name
 Please supply only supported device specifier options.

Comment: Does cocoapods automatically know which binary to choose?

Comment: @Awesome-o, I’m not sure I understand what you’re asking. CocoaPods builds all dependencies from source.

Comment: I thought Realm did something special here. If that's the case is RealmSwift source compatible with Swift 4? Anything special I need to do to get it to work or will it just work?

Comment: @bdash Do you know if RealmSwift is source compatible with Swift 4?

Comment: Yes, Realm Swift is source-compatible with all shipping Swift versions from Swift 3.0 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

As a followup to bdash's item 3 about how to build Realm manually from source, and to answer addzo's question about the xcodebuild error (that I ran into as well): Be sure that the iPhone 6 simulator is set up for your Xcode 9 to avoid that error.  I suppose Realm's build scripts must target it.  This solved it for me, anyhow.

Comment: Just a beginner here but if you import RealmSwift in the appdelegate file you will get that error and if you remove import RealmSwift from that appdelegate file the error goes away. You can import RealmSwift in the other relevant files. I did not use the pods method to incorporate RealmSwift used the technique used in Lynda.com with frameworks drag and dump. Very easy.