# iOS11 - Realm Framework not building

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, realm

I've downloaded Xcode 9 Beta 4 to fix a problem I have on my app in iOS 11.
However now Xcode won't let my build my app because Realm (and RealmSwift) are in Swift 3.1 and not 3.2.

Here is the message :

> Module compiled with Swift 3.1 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2

I don't use CocoaPods or Carthage. Do you know how can I solve this issue ?

Comment: Did you download the precompiled framework from the official site? You will need to build it yourself (either from binary of by using Carthage/CocoaPods) using Swift 3.2

Comment: How can I build it myself ? It's already in my project as a framework.

Comment: See [Building Realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa#building-realm)

Comment: The instructions I shared at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44641478/1991710 should produce a framework that can be used with Swift 3.2 and Swift 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use Realm with Swift 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640852/how-can-i-use-realm-with-swift-4)

Answer (score 0):

Make you selected command line tools for Xcode 9. You can find it Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools.

Then clean your project and build again. Should work.