# Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.2 - After XCode 9.1

Tags: swift, xcode, realm

I have been using a `Realm` for a while now without a problem until today when XCode self-auto-upgraded to `XCode 9.1`. I open my project and I get the following error.

> Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 3.2.2: /Users/UserName/MyApp/MyApp Watch App Extension/RealmSwift.framework/Modules/RealmSwift.swiftmodule/i386.swiftmodule

The error points to the `import RealmSwift`

I tried upgrading to `Realm version swift-4.0` but I keep getting the same error. The way I upgraded was by deleting the Realm frameworks from my project and adding version swift-4.0.

FYI - I'm not using Swift 4 in my project.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Just clean your project (`Cmd + K`) and build it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that Xcode 9.1 is using Swift 3.2.2, while the Realm Swift framework you're building against was built for Swift 4.0 (using Xcode 9.0). You need to update your Realm frameworks to versions built for the version of Swift that you're using, which you can find in the most recent release of Realm.

Comment: @ bdash But why it was working on XCode 9 if I was using the same `Realm version`?

Comment: Xcode 9.0 comes with Swift 3.2 and Swift 4.0. Xcode 9.1 comes with Swift 3.2.2 and Swift 4.0.2, which are not binary compatible with Xcode 9.0’s versions.

Comment: @ bdash Make sense. Upgrading to `swift-3.2.2` fixed the issue, thanks. Quick question. Right now I'm manually installing/upgrading Realm, is it better or recommended to install `Realm` using Cocoapods to avoid this kind of problems?

Comment: Dependency managers like CocoaPods and Carthage do make this situation slightly easier to deal with, but they don’t remove the need to be aware of it.

Comment: I'm currently using CocoPods in my project, what would be the best way to install it through `CocoaPods`? What do I add to the `Podfile`? I couldn't find any documentation on how to do it. Just `pod RalmSwift'? Where can I find information?

Comment: Realm’s documentation has instructions on how to integrate Realm Swift using CocoaPods. I’d suggest taking a look at it.

Comment: Found it. I didn't see it when I looked. I will give it try.

Comment: Interesting discussion however I suspect there is no way to get around the current incompatibility between Realm-iOS11.3-Swift 4.1 Xcode 9.3 without a computer science Phd. I believe Realm has to do the updating and I anxiously wait, God only knows for how long. The theoretical advantage of Apple's DB is that I assume it would always be compatible with updated Apple software (but that's a guess).

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44640852/how-can-i-use-realm-with-swift-4/44641478#44641478) for steps for using Realm with Xcode versions that Realm has yet to make a binary release for.